# Updating a scene in Unity with a script from Edit Mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add same components to different game objects in a scene in Unity. To make it faster I am trying to write a script that will do this for a list of game objects like (`enemy1, enemy2, enemy3`...).

I know that adding a script named `Enemy` I will do:

`gameObject.AddComponent<Enemy>();`

But the problem is once I stop the play mode the component is gone. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly select all the game objects (the list of enemies you mentioned) from the Hierarchy by holding `ctrl` and then add in the inspector the script `Enemy` to all of them.

However, if you want to use a script to do it, which can be executed outisde of the Play Mode you need to add `ExecuteInEditMode` before the script, like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TriggerEdit : MonoBehaviour
{
    // List of GameObjects
    String[] enemyList = {"enemy1", "enemy2", "enemy3"};
    
    void OnEnable()
    {
        foreach(String enemy in enemyList){
            go = GameObject.Find(enemy);
            go.AddComponent<Enemy>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to add that script to any game object in your scene. Everytime you want to trigger the script you just need to disable and enable the script `TriggerEdit` in the editor:

[image]

One problem with this approach is that everytime you enable the script, it will add a new component, independently if there is already a compoment of type `Enemy` in the game object, so you may end up with a lot of `Enemy` components. Something you can try then is to clean all `Enemy` components in the scene before adding anything else new. For example:

```
object[] enemiesToDelete = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>();

foreach(UnityEngine.Object enemyComponent in enemiesToDelete)
{
    DestroyImmediate(enemyComponent);
}
```